# radio select all and select none not working properly in jquery 1.10.1

Tags: jquery

my issue is happening only  in jquery 1.10.1. if i use jquery 1.8.3, it works fine.
I have a list with 'yes' and 'no' radio buttons, and 1 'select all' radio and 1 'select none' radio. i made a code so that the list selects all 'yes' radio buttons when i click the 'select all' radio, and same for 'select none' radio. the problem is thatthis only works once for each of these radio buttons. i mean that when i sleect the 'sselect all',radio it works, then i select the 'slelect none' radio, it works, then i go back to 'select all' radio and it does not work.code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.showme-btn').hover(function(){

        $(this).next('.showme').fadeToggle(200);
    //$(this).parent('.show-outer').toggleClass("show-outer-color");
    });
 $("input.allradioselect").click(function(){
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
 $("ul[class*='eachfield'] input.yesradio").attr("checked","true"); 
}
 });

  $("input.noradioselect").click(function(){

 if($(this).attr('checked', true)){
 //alert('ff');
$("ul[class*='eachfield'] input.noradio").attr("checked", "false");
}
 });
    });
```

html:

```
<ul class="cb commongap" style="background-color: #fff; float: left; width: 99%;">

    <li style="margin-left: 8px; width: 75%; float: right; text-align: right;"><img src="img/pointer.png" alt="pointer"/> Mark all questions as :  Yes <input type="radio" class="allradioselect" name="slelectallorno"/> or No <input type="radio" class="noradioselect" name="slelectallorno"/> </li>


    </ul>
<ul class="eachfield-title titlegap">
        <li class="eachfield-title-numbering">A.</li>
        <li class="ques">Have you received any medical treatment during the last five years or are you awaiting medical or surgical consultation, hospitalization, test or investigation?<span class="showme-btn">?</span>
        <div class="showme"> (You need not disclose matters relating to uncomplicated pregnancy, common colds, influenza, hay-fever or any minor ailment requiring a single consultation).(You need not disclose matters relating to uncomplicated pregnancy, common colds, influenza, hay-fever or any minor ailment requiring a single consultation).
        </div>
        <div class="cb"></div>



        </li>
    <li class="yes-no"><input type="radio" class="yesradio" name="selecta"/> </li>
        <li class="yes-no"><input type="radio" class="noradio" name="selecta"/> </li>


    </ul>
    <ul class="eachfield-title titlegap">
        <li class="eachfield-title-numbering">B.</li>
        <li class="ques">   Have you ever had any medical or surgical treatment, including investigations, tests, scans or X-Ray for any of the following illnesses or medical conditions: <span class="showme-btn">?</span>
        <div class="showme"> (You need not disclose matters relating to uncomplicated pregnancy, common colds, influenza, hay-fever or any minor ailment requiring a single consultation).(You need not disclose matters relating to uncomplicated pregnancy, common colds, influenza, hay-fever or any minor ailment requiring a single consultation).
        </div>
        <div class="cb"></div>



        </li>
        <li class="yes-no"><input type="radio" class="yesradio" name="selectb"/> </li>
        <li class="yes-no"><input type="radio"class="noradio" name="selectb"/> </li>


    </ul>
```

fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nvk6Y/
you can change the jquery version to 1.8.3 in this fiddle and see the difference.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.showme-btn').hover(function () {
        $(this).next('.showme').fadeToggle(200);
        //$(this).parent('.show-outer').toggleClass("show-outer-color");
    });
    $("input[name='slelectallorno']").click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'all') {
            $("ul[class*='eachfield'] input.yesradio").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("ul[class*='eachfield'] input.noradio").prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nvk6Y/3/)**